# THREEjs cant get a sphree to render to screen

Tags: three.js, webgl

hii i am trying to get a sphree to render into the screen. here is my js file.

```
function Earth()
{
    this.getEarth = init();

function init()
{
    var map = {map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/earth_surface_2048.jpg")};
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(map);
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,32,32);
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

function update()
{
    getEarth.rotation.x += .01;
}
}
```

and here is the script that is in the html file
threejs is included to the page.

```
    <script>

    var renderer = null;
    var scene = null;
    var camera = null;
    var mesh = null;
    var earth = null;

    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true } );
                renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth,container.offsetHeight);
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45,
                        container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight, 1, 4000 );

                earth = new Earth();
                scene.add(camera);
                scene.add(earth.getEarth);
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
    );


</script>
```

i get no erros from the debugger, so any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

earth.getEarth is probably null or a function. I remember scene.add() silently ignoring stuff it can't take, like undefined values and so on.

How about changing `var getEarth = init();` to `this.getEarth = init();` so that code outside of your class scope will see that variable in your earth object. Althought I would advice against using a method-like name for a variable containing an object.

Comment: soory for noticing just now, i have allready seen it and changed it, it still wont render.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: JSFiddle would be a good idea. Other thing that comes to mind is that both your camera and earth seems to be at position 0,0,0, so the camera might be inside your earth geometry. Faces are one-sided by default, they are invisible when looking from back/inside. You could try changing the camera or sphere location and/or set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide` so the sphere faces are visible from both front and back.

Comment: Yaku thanks you where right as soon as i seted the camera to z=3 i saw the shape, thx allot!